# PDF libraries that work in Windows Store applications

Tags: c#, pdf, window, itext

I Am Using itext.dll library for create the PDF in Windows8.1 applications. its works fine in local machine. but its not supporting while try to build in windows store. is there any solutions for use itext.dll Library or any other open source Library available for create the pdf in windows Store Applications?
 i had the error while try to build the application:

**Error Found:** The supported APIs test detected the following errors:

API System.ICloneable in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. itextsharp.dll calls this API.
API System.IO.FileSystemInfo in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. itextsharp.dll calls this API.
API System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. itextsharp.dll calls this API.
API System.Xml.XmlNode in SYSTEM.XML, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. itextsharp.dll calls this API.
API System.Collections.Stack in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. itextsharp.dll calls this API.
API System.Collections.Hashtable in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. itextsharp.dll calls this API.
API System.IO.FileStream in MSCORLIB, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. itextsharp.dll calls this API.
API System.Xml.XmlDocument in SYSTEM.XML, PUBLICKEYTOKEN=B77A5C561934E089 is not supported for this application type. itextsharp.dll calls this API.

Comment: You should ask here http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ recommendations for PDF libraries that work in Windows Store applications.